# Finding out what http requests were made by the user

Tags: html, http, http-headers, request

I am working on a project involving finding out what http requests were made by the user.

I have all the http request and response headers (but not the data), and I need to find out what content was requested by the user and what content was automatically sent (e.g. ads pages, streaming on the background, and all sorts of unrelevant content).
When recording the net traffic (even for a short period) alot of content gets generated, and most of it is not relevant.
since im no expert in http, i'd like some help with directions as of which headers I can safely use (assuming most web pages send them), and which headers might be omitted and so it will not be safe to rely on.

my current idea involves:
find all the html files, and check what the main html files were (no referrer or search engine referrer), and then recursively mark all the files called by these html files onward as relevant, and discard the rest.

the problem with this is that I've been told that I can't trust the referrer header, and I have no idea as of how to identify what html files were clicked by the user.
Every kind of help will be appreciated, sorry if the post is not formatted well, this is my first question here.

EDIT:
I've been told the question is'nt clear enough, so all I'm asking is for some way to determine which requests were triggered by the user and whic requests were automatically made

Answer (score 0):

To determine which request was send by the user itself you should look at the first request send through the connection and look at it's response body.

All external files referenced in this first body which then consecutively get send to the user are most likely to be send automatically without the users interaction.

Time passing between requests could also be an factor worth looking at.

Another thing you already mentioned yourself would be looking at the Referer header. As far as the [RFC 2616 14.36](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) goes it can be trusted, as the Referer header must not be sent if the Request URI comes from user input. Although there could be automatically send content which does not have the Referer header set, as it's optional.

Comment: although true, that is not what I asked for, I know how to recognize the url, what I need is help with recognizing what the user viewed and wanted from the rest of the traffic that is recieved (even on port 80)

Comment: so you just want to know which requests were triggered by the user and which requests were automatically send? Could you edit your question to be more clear about what you need?

Comment: i changed my answer, hope it can help a bit.

Comment: umm as I mentioned I already got to that conclusion, the question is how to find that first page, and I can't use "the first page sent" as a factor since I recieve many headers and need to find out the relevant pages from them (so it might work for the first one, but not for the rest of the pages.

Comment: can you distinguish between differten tcp connections? Do you have timestamps? Take the first request send through a new tcp connection as guaranteed user input. And take actions send after a given idle time as user input. At some point you probably have to deal with possibilites and can't make certain assumptions anymore i guess.

Comment: what do you mean by different tco connections ? I'm new to networks

Comment: each http request as an underlying TCP connection. Though the same user/client pair can reuse this connection multiple times, each new user initiates a new TCP connection. If you can distinguish between these connections you have at least the first request done by a new user.

Comment: then no, I'm recording the whole network traffic the whole time, and all I have is the headers.